# Let $F: \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} $ be defined by $F(x)(t)=g(t)x(h(t)).$ Show that $F$ is continuous in the product topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $g,h : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be arbitary functions. Let $F: \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} $ be defined by $F(x)(t)=g(t)x(h(t)).$ Show that $F$ is continuous in the product topology. Hint: You can use the fact that a map $f :X \to \Pi_j Y_j$ is continous iff every $f_j :X \to Y_j$ is continuous.

From the hint it seems that I would like to get a grasp of the component functions and deteremine that they’re continuous, but I feel a bit thrown off by the construction here. It seems that $F$ takes as an input a real valued function (since $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} $ is the set of functions from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$) and outputs a real valued function? ”Points” of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} $ are real valued functions?

What is the role of the parameter $t$ here and where does it even come from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "points" of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ are functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Here, $t$ is just a real number. You define the function
$$
F : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto g(-)\cdot x(h(-)).
$$
This is well-defined, since $g$ and $h$ are known real-valued functions and because then $g(-)\cdot x(h(-))$ is indeed a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, since $g(t)\cdot x(h(t)) \in \mathbb{R}$. I admit that it is a bit confusing, because it is unusual to denote a real-valued function by $x$.

I hope this helps!